# IBM watson assistant: integrate IBM watson chatbot with android API 17

Tags: ibm-watson, android-sdk-tools

I want to integrate my IBM watson assistant skill into android application with SDK version of 17. **Which android SDK version of watson should be used to integrate watson assistant skill with android API 17**? I tried with "com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.5.0" but it supports API 19 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the minimum supported Android API level is 19 for the Watson Developer Cloud SDK.

Check this out: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk